# How to distribute tasks between servers where each task must be done by only one server?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed, polling, distributed-system

**Goal:** There are X number backend servers. There are Y number of tasks. Each task must be done only by one server. The same task ran by two different servers should not happen.

There are tasks which include continuous work for an indefinite amount of time, such as polling for data. The same server can keep doing such a task as long as the server stays alive.

**Problem:** How to reassign a task if the server executing it dies? If the server dies, it can't mark the task as open. What are efficient ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way you define your problem makes it sloppy to reason about. What you actually is looking for called a "distributed lock".

Let's start with a simpler problem: assume you have only two concurrent servers `S1, S2` and a single task `T`. The *safety* property you stated remains as is: at no point in time both `S1` and `S2` may process task `T`. How could that be achieved? The following strategies come to mind:

1. Implement an algorithm that *deterministically* maps task to a responsible server. For example, it could be as stupid as `if task.name.contains('foo') then server1.process(task) else server2.process(task)`. That works and indeed might fit some real world requirements out there, yet such an approach is a dead end: a) you have to know how many server would you have upfront, statically and - the most dangerous - 2) you can *not* tolerate either server being down: if, say, `S1` is taken off then there is nothing you can do with `T` right now except then just wait for `S1` to come back online. These drawbacks could be softened, optimized - yet there is no way to get rid of them; escaping these deficiencies requires a more *dynamic* approach.
2. Implement an algorithm that would allow `S1` and `S2` to agree upon who is responsible for the `T`. Basically, you want both `S1` and `S2` to come to a *consensus* about (assumed, not necessarily needed) `T.is_processed_by = "S1"` or `T.is_processed_by = "S2"` property's *value*. Then your requirement translates to the "at any point in time `is_process_by` is seen by both servers in the same way". Hence "consensus": "an agreement (between the servers) about a `is_processed_by` value". Having that eliminates all the "too static" issues of the previous strategy: actually, you are no longer bound to 2 servers, you could have had `n, n > 1` servers (provided that your distributed consensus works for a chosen `n`), however it is not prepared for accidents like unexpected power outage. It could be that `S1` won the competition, `is_processed_by` became equal to the `"S1"`, `S2` agreed with that and... `S1` went down and did nothing useful....

...so you're missing the last bit: the "liveness" property. In simple words, you'd like your system to continuously progress whenever possible. To achieve that property - among many other things I am not mentioning - you have to make sure that spontaneous server's death is monitored and - once it happened - not a single task `T` gets stuck for indefinitely long. How do you achieve that? That's another story, a typical piratical solution would be to copy-paste the good old TCP's way of doing essentially the same thing: meet the [keepalive](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) approach.

OK, let's conclude what we have by now:

1. Take any implementation of a "distributed locking" which is equivalent to "distributed consensus". It could be a [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) done [correctly](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Locks), a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) running a [`serializable` transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) or whatever alike.
2. Per each unprocessed or stuck task `T` in your system, make all the free servers `S` to race for that lock. Only one of them guaranteed to win and all the rest would surely loose.
3. Frequently enough push sort of TCP's `keepalive` notifications per each processing task or - at least - per each alive server. Missing, let say, three notifications in a sequence should be taken as server's death and all of it's tasks should be re-marked as `"stuck"` and (eventually) reprocessed in the previous step.

And that's it.

P.S. [Safety & liveness properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_and_liveness_properties) is something you'd definitely want to be aware of once it comes to distributed computing.

Answer (score 0):

Try rabbitmq worker queues
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

It has an acknowledgement feature so if a task fails or server cashes it will automatically replay your task. Based on your specific use case u can setup retries, etc

Comment: What if the server where the RabbitMQ work queue is running crashes? Is there support for high availability RabbitMQ work queues? Otherwise, the problem might repeat in that how do we keep only single work queue running.

Comment: So basically theres one place where the queue itself is stored which is can be called the rabbitmq server. The workers are just your regular app nodes subcribed to the server. If the worker crashes, server would not hv received acknowledgement so it will replay the message to another worker assuming the task didnt succeed. If the server itself crashes it has a persisted option to read back the unacknowledge messages from disk when it comes back online. If you want even higher level of security then you can consider a cluster of rabbitMq servers or even managed rabbitmq server in the cloud

Answer (score 0):

"Problem: How to reassign a task if the server executing it dies? If the server dies, it can't mark the task as open. What are efficient ways to accomplish this?"

You are getting into a known problem in distributed systems, how does a system makes decisions when the system is partitioned. Let me elaborate on this.

A simple statement "server dies" requires quite a deep dive on what does this actually mean. Did the server lost power? Is it the network between your control plane and the server is down (and the task is keep running)? Or, maybe, the task was done successfully, but the failure happened just before the task server was about to report about it? If you want to be 100% correct in deciding the current state of the system - that the same as to say that the system has to be 100% consistent.

This is where CAP theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) comes to play. Since your system may be partitioned at any time (a worker server may get disconnected or die - which is the same state) and you want to be 100% correct/consistent, this means that the system won't be 100% available.

To reiterate the previous paragraph: if the system suspects a task server is down, the system as a whole will have to come to a stop, till it will be able to determine on what happened with the particular task server.

Trade off between consistency and availability is the core of distributed systems. Since you want to be 100% correct, you won't have 100% availability.

While availability is not 100%, you still can improve the system to make it as available as possible. Several approaches may help with that.

Simplest one is to alert a human when the system suspects it is down. The human will get a notification (24/7), wake up, login and do a manual check on what is going on. Whether this approach works for your case - it depends on how much availability you need. But this approach is completely legit and is widely used in the industry (those engineers carrying pagers).

More complicated approach is to let the system to fail over to another task server automatically, if that is possible. Few options are available here, depending on type of task.

First type of task is a re-runnable one, but they have to exist as a single instance. In this case, the system uses "STONITH" (shoot the other node in the head) technic to make sure previous node is dead for good. For example, in a cloud the system would actually kill the whole container of task server and then start a new container as a failover.

Second type of tasks is not re-runnable. For example, a task of transferring money from account A to be B is not (automatically) re-runnable. System does not know if the task failed before or after the money were moved. Hence, the fail over needs to do extra steps to calculate the outcome, which may also be impossible if network is not working correctly. In this cases the system usually goes to halt, till it can make 100% correct decision.

None of these options will give 100% of availability, but they can do as good as possible due to nature of distributed systems.

Comment: Please stop making a cult out of "CAP theorem". It does not state what you've advocating neither needed to reason by the OP's problem.